# Rails link to file in public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have a file `data.txt` in the `public` folder of my Rails project. I want to link to it from one of the pages in my project using `link_to`. How can I do it?

If I do

```
<%= link_to "here", "data.txt" %>
```

it links to `domain.com/data.txt` instead of `domain.com/my_project/data.txt`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want to access the file here:

```
<%= link_to "here", "/my_project/data.txt" %>
```

Comment: In link should be reference to `root_path` or `root_url`, as in answer below. Application can be placed to the arbitrary place in URL structure (not necessary root). Hardcoding `/my_project` isn't good.

Comment: No, you are wrong.  Root url could be anything, any controller#action.  Using it as chris mentions may work as a default, but it wouldn't go to the 'my_project' folder.  Not sure why you would use root_url this way, that's usually used as a stand_alone method, not as a method to generate a url below the root.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
<%= link_to 'Sitemap', root_url+'my_sitemap.svg', { target: '_blank' } %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with:

```
link_to 'Download sample', root_path + 'data/invoices/sample.pdf'
```

**Update 2018-08-09**

- Performance does not matter if you generate single link (benchmark it if you many of them)
- Probably `"#{root_path}data/invoices/sample.pdf"` is much simpler